# Attempting to link projects to show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

So I have a list of projects, and I try to make an each do in wich each of them should lead to its own project, but instead I get an error 'unexpected keyword_ensure', expecting end-of-input

, however, I keep checking them all and none seems to be missing.

```
    <h1 id=title>Projects</h1>
        <div id="post_wrap" class="skiny_wrap">
            <% @projects.each do |project|  %>
                <div class="post">
                    <h2 class="name"><%= project.name %> </h2>
                    <p class="description"><%= project.description %> </p>

                    <% if project.has_photo? %>
                         <%= link_to project.name, project do %>
                                 <div class="img_container" style="background-image: url(/photo_store/<%=project1.id%>.<%=project1.extension%>)"></div>
                         <% end %>
                    <%else%>
                            <p> theres nothing here </p>

                    <%end%>

                    <p class="category"><%= project1.category %> </p>
                    <p class="date"><%= project1.created_at.strftime('%A, %B %d') %> </p>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <%end%>
                <% end %>

        </div>
```

What is going wrong? I can imagine one, is that that is not how you are meant to link to show however it is what my investigation lead to, please help me out.

```
<br><br>
<h2><%=@project.name%></h2>
<br>
<%=@project.link%>
<br><br>
<%=@project.description%>
<br><br>
Theme: <%=@project.category%>
<br><br>
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@project) %>
<%= link_to "Delete", post_path(@project), method: :delete, data:{ } %>
```

That is the Erb to the show, as you can see is very simple..

Comment: You seem to have an extra <% end %> tag in the first code snippet

Comment: I have added and removed every single one of them trying to track it but it didnt seem to work could you please point out wich?

Comment: at the end of first group of code, you have `<%end%>` followed on the next line by `<% end %>`, you should only have one.

Comment: I managed to fix it with your help guys, thank you very much